# How to inspect nbak state of a Firebird database

Tags: c#, firebird, database-backups, firebird-3.0, firebird-.net-provider

Is there a way in C# to inspect the nbak state of a Firebird database?

The state in the database header would be set to `nbak_state_diff` or `nbak_state_normal`. But how do I actually read this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
Select MON$BACKUP_STATE From MON$DATABASE
```

Quote from https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref-appx05-mondb.html

> Current physical backup (nBackup) state:
>   0 - normal
>   1 - stalled
>   2 - merge

Also see **c:\Program Files\Firebird\Firebird_3_0\doc\README.monitoring_tables.txt**

P.S. for C#-related questions it is often faster to ask in a dedicated Google forum,  see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/firebird-.net-provider/info